# Flutter How to Sync between Name and Calculate Distance

Tags: flutter, dart

I have dataMarket with name, latitude, and longitude.
tats latitude and longitude are used to calculate the distance between the user and the market.

**Data.dart**

```
class Market{
  static List dataMarket = [
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Alfamart',
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Minis'
        latitudeDest: -6.211269,
        longitudeDest: 106.615574),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Star Market'
        latitudeDest: -6.223254,
        longitudeDest:  106.703905),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Allmark'
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Eig Store'
        latitudeDest: -6.178293, 
        longitudeDest: 106.631862,),
  ];
}

class Data{
  String nameDest;
  var latitudeDest;
  var longitudeDest;

  Data({
     this.nameDest
     this.latitudeDest,
     this.longitudeDest});
}
```

**MyListMarket.dart**

```
import 'package:example/Data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

 class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  var lastLatitude;
  var lastLongitude;
  final dataInstance = Market.dataMarket;
  var newSortRange = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_initUserLocation();
  }

  Future<int> _initUserLocation() async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      Position position = await Geolocator()
             .getLastKnownPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
      lastLatitude = position.latitude;
      lastLongitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Permission Denied");
    }
    return 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initUserLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          if (lastLatitude == null || lastLongitude == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              newSortRange.add(0.00);
            }
          } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              //calculating distance with lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2

              var p = 0.017453292519943295;
              var c = cos;
              var a = 0.5 -
                  c((dataInstance[i].latitudeDest - lastLatitude) * p) / 2 +
                  c(lastLatitude * p) *
                      c(dataInstance[i].latitudeDest * p) *
                      (1 -
                          c((dataInstance[i].longitudeDest - lastLongitude) *
                              p)) /
                      2;
              newSortRange.add(12742 * asin(sqrt(a)));
            }
          }
          newSortRange.sort();
          print(newSortRange);
          return ListView.separated(
              key: PageStorageKey<String>('aKey'),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: newSortRange.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(251, 251, 251, 1),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        trailing: Text(
                          newSortRange[index].toStringAsFixed(2) + "\nKM",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(
                  height: 0.0,
                  thickness: 0.7,
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but on this code not sync data between nameDest and calculate distance. How to solve this?

maybe can I store calculate distance into data array newRange null?

```
class Market{
  static List dataMarket = [
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Alfamart',
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Minis'
        latitudeDest: -6.211269,
        longitudeDest: 106.615574,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Star Market'
        latitudeDest: -6.223254,
        longitudeDest:  106.703905,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Allmark'
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Eig Store'
        latitudeDest: -6.178293, 
        longitudeDest: 106.631862,
        newRange: null),
  ];
}

class Data{
  String nameDest;
  var latitudeDest;
  var longitudeDest;
  var newRange;

  Data({
     this.nameDest
     this.latitudeDest,
     this.longitudeDest,
     this.newRange});
}
```

if can store calculate the distance in **newRange**. so how I can store data into the array?
or is there another way to keep the name and distance data in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right path, you can achieve using that new variable in class. However, for that you have to create your own sorting algorithm to swap object's position in list also.

Following full demo help you more to understand.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  var lastLatitude;
  var lastLongitude;
  final dataInstance = Market.dataMarket;
  var newSortRange = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_initUserLocation();
  }

  Future<int> _initUserLocation() async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      //     Position position = await Geolocator()
      //       .getLastKnownPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
      lastLatitude = -6.163891; //position.latitude;
      lastLongitude = 106.628915; //position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Permission Denied");
    }
    return 1;
  }

  void bubbleSort() {
    int n = newSortRange.length;
    int i, step;
    for (step = 0; step < n; step++) {
      for (i = 0; i < n - step - 1; i++) {
        if (newSortRange[i] > newSortRange[i + 1]) {
          swap(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void swap(int i) {
    double temp = newSortRange[i];
    newSortRange[i] = newSortRange[i + 1];
    newSortRange[i + 1] = temp;
    Data _data = dataInstance[i];
    dataInstance[i] = dataInstance[i + 1];
    dataInstance[i + 1] = _data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initUserLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          if (lastLatitude == null || lastLongitude == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              newSortRange.add(0.00);
            }
          } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              //calculating distance with lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2

              var p = 0.017453292519943295;
              var c = cos;
              var a = 0.5 -
                  c((dataInstance[i].latitudeDest - lastLatitude) * p) / 2 +
                  c(lastLatitude * p) *
                      c(dataInstance[i].latitudeDest * p) *
                      (1 -
                          c((dataInstance[i].longitudeDest - lastLongitude) *
                              p)) /
                      2;
              newSortRange.add(12742 * asin(sqrt(a)));
              dataInstance[i].newRange = 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
            }
          }
          bubbleSort();
          //newSortRange.sort();
          print(newSortRange);
          return ListView.separated(
              key: PageStorageKey<String>('aKey'),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: newSortRange.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(251, 251, 251, 1),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        trailing: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              newSortRange[index].toStringAsFixed(2) + "\nKM",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            Text('${dataInstance[index].newRange}')
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(
                  height: 0.0,
                  thickness: 0.7,
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Market {
  static List<Data> dataMarket = [
    Data(
        nameDest: 'Alfamart',
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915,
        newRange: -1),
    Data(
        nameDest: 'Minis',
        latitudeDest: -6.211269,
        longitudeDest: 106.615574,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest: 'Star Market',
        latitudeDest: -6.223254,
        longitudeDest: 106.703905,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest: 'Allmark',
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915,
        newRange: null),
    Data(
        nameDest: 'Eig Store',
        latitudeDest: -6.178293,
        longitudeDest: 106.631862,
        newRange: null),
  ];
}

class Data {
  var nameDest;
  var latitudeDest;
  var longitudeDest;
  var newRange;

  Data({this.nameDest, this.latitudeDest, this.longitudeDest, this.newRange});
}
```